# in c printf() returns what

Tags: c, printf

in c printf() returns what?

Comment: What has become of the good old tradition of reading the fine manual?

Answer (score 8):

`printf` returns:

- On success, the **total number of
  characters** written.
- On failure, a **negative number**.

Answer (score 6):

1. Point your browser to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com/);
2. Search "printf c";
3. Almost [any result](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) you'll get will tell you:

> #### Return Value
>
> On success, the total number of characters written is returned.
> On failure, a negative number is returned.

Was that so difficult?

Comment: Which will get you common practice in almost all cases, which is very different from asking what it actually returns.

Comment: This is the best answer. For any questions as trivial as "what does C function x return", the above should be your first resource. Leave SO for more "interesting" problems and questions. Futhermore, reading a paragraph or two worth of documentation to get an answer is genereally time well spent (I call it colateral learning).

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. I provided exactly the same information provided by all the other answers, **including the one with three upvotes** and the information needed to find that answer without spamming SO; I don't even think I've been impolite.
NealB expressed perfectly my position on the topic; I like to give complete and insightful answers to serious/interesting questions, but for such things teaching to use Google is the best thing you can do. In other forums in which I often write such a question may even have been closed with a (polite) RTFM.

Comment: I agree with you - your answer is a polite RTFM and totally valid for this question ... +1

Answer (score 1):

It returns the number of characters printed. See `man fprintf` for simple questions like this.

From the man page:

*These functions return the number of characters printed (not including the trailing '\0' used to end output to strings) or a negative value if an output error occurs, except for snprintf() and vsnprintf(), which return the number of characters that would have been printed if the n were unlimited (again, not including the final '\0').*

Answer (score 1):

Number of characters (not including the trailing \0) printed on success, negative value on failure. see man printf.

Comment: Don't count on it returning `-1` on failure; it can return any negative value.

Comment: Thats correct, I will fix the answer. Thanks

Comment: Note that printf() does not print the trailing null - which is why it is not included in the count.

Answer (score 1):

> The result of "printf" is the number of characters written. If a write error occurs, "printf" returns a negative number. (ANSI standard)

Even wikipedia has a whole article about [printf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf), where you can find the different return values for different languages and times.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what it says it returns in any decent [library reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)

> On success, the total number of characters written is returned.
>   On failure, a negative number is returned.