# Assigning a printf statement to a int variable

Tags: c, string

See the following code:

```
int i={
          printf("c" "++")
       };
```

it prints c++ and returns 3 to i.
how it is assigning 3 to i?
need explanation!

Comment: The number of bytes output. RTM.

Comment: @WeatherVane care to make this a comprehensible answer?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845323/what-does-printf-return

Answer (score 3):

[`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) returns the number of bytes written to `stdout`. `"c++"` is exactly three bytes long (not counting the null-terminator).

By the way, you really don't need to use the curly braces, you can simply do `int i=printf("c" "++");`.

Comment: @chux, __that's why__ I'm not counting it (there is one in the string itself, but it isn't printed, certainly)