# what will be the o/p of this c code? why?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [in c printf() returns what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727922/in-c-printf-returns-what)

what will be the o/p of this c code? why?

```
i=printf("hellow"); 
printf("%d",i);
```

Thanks..

Comment: Homework?   Do you have any ideas what it might put out?  Why?  Have you run this code?

Comment: Why don't you run and see it yourself?

Comment: What does your manual say it should do? You did read the manual entry on printf before asking, right?

Comment: o/p? what? please speak English here..

Answer (score 4):

Homework? Anyway, printf returns the number of characters printed. That should help.

Answer (score 0):

Output is

**hellow6**

as printf returns number of characters it has printed...

Answer (score 0):

**Output will be:**

```
hellow6
```

**Reason:**

The first `printf` will print 6 characters (`"hellow"`), which will be the return value, assigned to `i`.

The second `printf` will print `i`, which will be 6.

Since there is no NewLine or other separator specified, the two will be run together as `hellow6`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you ran the code and see the output:

**hellow6**

The explanation is, printf returns the number of characters it was able to write successfully.